# Hungarian homographs

Tags: homonymy, hungarian

I've been living in Hungary for a year now and I've been slowly learning the language, so naturally a question arouse: are there any homographs in Hungarian?
When I'm talking about `homograph` I mean a word that has the following characteristics (as per many dictionaries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph):

1. *shares the same written form* as another word;
2. has a *different meaning*;
3. (and) *sounds different*.

   I've been looking a lot on the web and I've been asking my Hungarian friends and coworkers and it seems that even the word *homograph* doesn't really have a meaning for them (at least for the people I've asked), let alone have some homographs in Hungarian.

Comment: Despite the "close" voters, I think this could be an excellent question if put in a slightly more general form, e.g. "Are there any languages that do not have homographs?"

Comment: Maybe: the question is, who re-writes the question? That's not a natural generalization of the actually-asked question, though it might inspire someone to ask a related generalized question. This question incorrectly holds that homographs *are* pronounced different, not *may be*.

Comment: As @user6726 notes, homographs refer to meaning, not sound. The term you are asking for is "heteronym". Hungarian certainly has many homographs in the sense of lemmata with multiple meanings; but as it's now written in a phonemic system it's not likely to have any heteronyms.

Comment: We can always close, edit and reopen it. @fdb or i can put up the question

Comment: Ok, so should I just close the question here? Or just rewrite it?
It is indeed wrongly written in the question that I was looking for hungarian homographs when clearly I meant heteronyms - this is my bad.
Also, it could be useful for other people that (like me) try to learn a totally different language and inherently stumble upon these kind of questions so I see the point in extending / generalising the question.

Comment: Perhaps certain compound words like this could exist. The use of digraphs in Hungarian like "sz" and the writing together of compound words leads to some ambiguity when going from spelling to pronunciation

Answer (score 3):

The spelling of Hungarian is phonetic, so you won't really find any words spelt identically but pronounced differently.

There is one exception. There are two different *e* sounds in the language, one more open and one more closed. They are distinguished by a substantial fraction of speakers, but not in the "standard" language. Both are spelt as *e*. When there is a specific need to distinguish them in writing (e.g. in linguistics texts), the closed one is spelt as *ë*.

There are many minimal pairs, e.g. *mëntëk* can mean *you (plural) go* or *I save* while *mëntek* means *they went*.

Comment: This is not true, since the Hungarian alphabet contains a number of di- or trigraph letters (gy, sz, dzs, etc.), which can also occur in geminate form (ggy, ssz, ddzs, etc.). It is conceivable that a sequence of 2–4 characters spanning a morpheme boundary may coincidentally resemble a di- or trigraph letter. This leads to the possibility of ambiguity in meaning and pronunciation. I'll try to think of some examples and post an answer of my own.

Answer (score 2):

Hungarian exhibits a much closer correspondence between spelling and pronunciation than English, but there are still a few cases that give rise to ambiguity.  Usually this ambiguity is only potential, because one valid pronunciation corresponds to an actual Hungarian word, while the other valid pronunciation results in nonsense.  Sometimes, however, both valid pronunciations correspond to actual words with very different meanings.

Recall that the Hungarian alphabet consists of 44 letters, including one trigraph ⟨dzs⟩ and the seven digraphs ⟨cs⟩, ⟨dz⟩, ⟨ly⟩, ⟨ny⟩, ⟨sz⟩, ⟨ty⟩, and ⟨zs⟩.  All of the consonants can also occur in geminate forms by doubling their first (or only) letter.  For the digraphs and trigraph, these are ⟨ccs⟩, ⟨ddz⟩, ⟨lly⟩, ⟨nny⟩, ⟨ssz⟩, ⟨tty⟩, ⟨zzs⟩, and ⟨ddzs⟩.  What all this means is that certain sequences of two to four glyphs could be interpreted as a sequence of one, two, three, or four letters, depending on the context.  So if you see ⟨cs⟩ within a word, it might be the digraph letter ⟨cs⟩ (pronounced /t͡ʃ/) or it might be the unigraph letter ⟨c⟩ followed by the unigraph letter ⟨s⟩ (pronounced /t͡sʃ/).

The orthographic sequence **⟨lécsín⟩** is an example of a homograph with two different, equally valid pronunciations and meanings:  it can be analyzed either as the compound ***lé* ('liquid') + *csín* ('elegance')**, in which case it is pronounced **/ˈleˌt͡ʃiːn/**, or as the compound ***léc* ('batten') + *sín* ('rail')**, in which case it is pronounced **/ˈlet͡sˌʃiːn/**.  Admittedly this example is somewhat contrived; while *lécsín* in the sense of a batten rail is attested (for example, in this [book on poultry farming](http://www.mezogazdasagikonyvtar.hu/assets/digitarchiv/POLONYI_Magyar-parlagi-baromfi-vedelme_1930_OCR.pdf)), I haven't been able to find any real-world uses of the "liquid elegance" sense. Still, I suspect that that sense would be understood by native speakers if the word were used in the right context (say, in a whiskey advertisement).

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the question: You mean something like "bank" - of a river, a place to store money or "to bank" as a verb. The reason why it is hard to think of a word which fits the description *might* be because the language is inherently built so that words quickly morph based on context. Which also implies that there is a lot of meaning packed into non-noun words unlike German and English. Germans can combine different nouns like `Esstischreparaturausbildungslizenzbehörde` (dinner table repair training licence authority) though.

```
Eszik - [He/She/It] eats.
Ehetetlen - Inedible.
Ehetetlenség - Inedibility (does not exist in English). "The inedibility of wood is rather displeasing."
Ehetetlensége - [His/Her/Its] inedibility.
Ehetetlenségének - For his/her/its inedibility (as of referencing it).
```

Not that these words make too much sense - however they are grammatically correct and understandable, just as the German example. Another point is that the sound of words is strictly bound to how they are written. The letters reflect exactly how to pronounce them, thus the requirement for 3. should be basically impossible to ever be fulfilled in Hungarian. Some examples:

```
Bor - Wine (alcoholic beverage).
Bőr - Skin/Leather.
Sor - Line.
Sör - Beer.
```

Note: I am actually not an alcoholic. The letters are always adjusted to match the different sound of the word with a different meaning, so it's different than English, where you have to know or figure out the pronunciation of words (`the` can have at least 2 ways to be pronounced based on the word following up on it). And I myself recognized that I would have difficulties to recognize what is meant if somebody mistakes letters like o, ó, ő, ö, even though I speak 3 languages (if you don't count programming languages). So I blatantly assume it may be a rather common issue for people understanding foreigners trying to speak Hungarian who make pronunciation errors. But when reading, it's often rather clear what is meant.

All of this being said, exceptions apply as the comments below pointed out: `házszám` for example makes it ambiguous how to pronounce it, as it's a compound of two words: `ház` and `szám`. Another example is `szám` - which means both "number" and "my mouth", however the pronunciation is identical. And then there is this [not too excessive list of rare exceptions on Wikipedia for homophones](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homof%C3%B3n_magyar_szavak_list%C3%A1ja).

Comment: "The letters reflect exactly how to pronounce them"—not entirely. Hungarian digraph letters like "sz" and "zs" can cause ambiguity, because they aren't pronounced the same as the combinations of separate letters that occur in compound words, but they do look the same. The [Wikipedia article on the Hungarian alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_alphabet) gives "házszám" as an example of a word where you have to know the proper division of the compound (ház + szám) in order to alphabetize the word; you also need to know this to pronounce it correctly.

Comment: I don't know if there are any "homographs" based on this in Hungarian, though (a famous example in German of two compounds that look the same but have different pronunciations is "Wachstube" as Wach.stube vs Wachs.tube).

Comment: I guess you could argue that in Hungarian, a pair of words like this would not really count as "homographs", because the words would be spelled with different sequences of letters from the perspective of Hungarian speakers, who treat "sz" and "zs" as letters of their own—but the different spellings would still look the same.

Comment: I think you're overlooking the case where some surface form clashes with a different form, for example the base form, of another lemma.  For one there are overloaded endings like *-i* and *-ik* which are both morphological and derivational.

Comment: https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homofón_magyar_szavak_listája is also worth reading, with loans the possibilities are near infinite, I think *bután* vs *bután* would qualify.

Comment: @sumelic - True, didn't thought about that. -- A. M. Bittingmayer - Also true. However these seem like very rare exceptions, especially compared with other languages. Which would also imply that people who learn Hungarian may not encounter such issues. -- I didn't meant to speak in absolutes, I am just a mortal non-linguist! Exceptions always seem to apply in languages, I only know the general rule.

Comment: I mean take the example of *bank*, although I think you are confusing German and English senses, but anyway let's take the senses you mentioned.  It originally meant the place to sit, and then that got extended to mean the financial institution.  That happens in Hungarian too.  Then the other possibility is that two words had distinct roots, but their pronunciation merged.  That happens in Hungarian too.  And then another possibility is that the word had two senses in another meaning, and then the figurative sense was borrowed into Hungarian.

Comment: Is a word with multiple senses or multiple etymologies not a homograph?  And then there are the homographs that occur in other ways, because of overlapping surface forms, those could have different parts of speech.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: Remember that the body of the question asks for words that have different pronunciations as well as different meanings.

Comment: @A. M. Bittlingmayer - Oof, corrected it. Luckily the English `bank` has many meanings. With that I just wanted to clarify the 3 rules set by the question. Also, it has no multiple meanings in Hungarian, only the financial institute. The processes you mentioned sure occur, but with the few exceptions mentioned, 99%+ of words are really just pronounced as they are written based on each letter. Even words taken from or shared with other languages get Hungarized like `múzsa` (muse) or `konzervatív` (the í) to adjust for the pronunciation.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, but I was responding to this answer, which mentioned *Bank* vs *Bank*, which does not qualify then.